# How to auto add more Data to Endless scrolling in adapterview and recyclerview by retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Have you ever faced this problem while getting some data on the scroll and interact?

Suppose that on a page there are 5 items by default. If the scroll reaches the bottom of the page, 5 new products will be called from the server and added to the previous list, and if the user has 5 more views and the scroll has reached the end of screen, 5 newer product are added to the list.

But unfortunately, the problem is that when the first one scrolls down, the new product will not be added to the end of the list, and because there are slider products, each of the new products will be added as the second image to the old sliders. Do not go to the bottom of the list

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_navi"
    tools:context="mypro.afaco.com.afacoooo.Products.User_postFragment">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pishfarz" />


    <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/na"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/im"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and here is the method:

```
public void GetData(final String user_id){
        String info=user_id;
        final ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog(getContext());

        Log.e("info",info);
        G.getMyAPI().User_Post(info).enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {

                layout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.e("response",String.valueOf(response.body().get(0).getId()));

                    if (response.body().size()>0){
                        size=response.body().size();
                        adapter = new Products_Adapter(getFragmentManager(),response.body(), getContext(),getActivity());
                        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(manager);
                        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert.showDialog_error(getContext(), "Your connection to the server has been disconnected");

                    }

//                    layout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                else {
                    alert.showDialog_error(getContext(), "Your connection to the server has been disconnected");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                layout.setRefreshing(false);

                Log.e("Error_user_post",t.getMessage());
                alert.showDialog_error(getContext(), "Your connection to the server has been disconnected");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Answer (score 0):

So as you said, you want a view with default 5 items and when user scroll at the bottom, it will load more 5 items and append at the bottom of view, right? Correct me if I misunderstood

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //.......
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
            {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
            totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
            scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
            {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    addDataToList();// in this function you will call api with Retrofit and get new data. Base on ur api params and how it works. 
Ex: My api i wil send pageIndex = 1 ( then +1 after scroll to bottom) and pagesize = 5( which items you want to received).
After call API success you will update to RecycleView. 
                } else {
                    // Scrolling down
                }
            }
        }


    });}
```

}

You can find more examples in here and code in their Github:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-vZ1g_G1Zo&t=193s

Comment: Yes, it is
But unfortunately, adding 5 new items
Consistency in information is an earlier option

Comment: Thankful
I used your code, the new product was added to the end of the list, but the problem was not resolved and new product images added to the old product slider.